# Facebook redirect in application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

When i using `redirect`, `header location` or `top.location.href` in facebook application, facebook open it in new browser tab, when i run the same code without facebook app - all works fine, redirect page opens in the same tab. how can i avoid that...

Answer (score 0):

Define $page_tab_url to return to whatever page U want and `echo ("<script>top.location.href = '" . $page_tab_url  ."'<script>");`

Comment: it still open in new browser tab.